# Detect if app got focus due to UILocalNotification

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I'm making an app that keeps track of some reminders that repeats with an user defined interval.

I've made it so when the alert displays, the action title says "Renew". When you click this, the app opens, and here I want to create the next reminder, but the problem is that I don't know if the app opens because the notification button was tapped or if the notification fired while the app was running.

Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The 'correct' way to do this is to examine your NSApplication's applicationState property in the application:didReceiveRemoteNotification: method of your delegate.

From the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/IPhoneOSClientImp/IPhoneOSClientImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103-SW4) for handling local notifications:

> iOS Note: In iOS, you can determine whether an application is launched
>   as a result of the user tapping the action button or whether the
>   notification was delivered to the already-running application by
>   examining the application state. In the delegate’s implementation of
>   the application:didReceiveRemoteNotification: or
>   application:didReceiveLocalNotification: method, get the value of the
>   applicationState property and evaluate it. If the value is
>   UIApplicationStateInactive, the user tapped the action button; if the
>   value is UIApplicationStateActive, the application was frontmost when
>   it received the notification.

This is similar to your solution using flags set in applicationWillEnterForeground and applicationDidBecomeActive but with system support.

Answer (score 13):

I don't know if my question was unclear but it seems that I got 4 different answers that all misinterpreted my question :P

However, I discovered that the didReceiveLocalNotivication happens between willEnterForeground and didBecomeActive, so I did this to determine if the app was already open or not:

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
{
    NSLog(@"Opened from notification? %@", wasInactive ? @"yes!" : @"no!");
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    wasInactive = YES;
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    wasInactive = NO;

}
```

Comment: Simpler than this, scrap the stuff in `applicationWillEnterForeground:` and `applicationDidBecomeActive:` entirely and just check `application.applicationState` in `application: didReceiveLocalNotification:` instead. If the application state is `UIApplicationStateActive`, you received the notification while the app was running. If it's `UIApplicationStateInactive` or `UIApplicationStateBackground`, you received it while the app was resuming. By the way, I suspect your current version will fail when bringing the app back to the foreground during a background task, though I need to test that.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

or

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
```

[Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application%3adidFinishLaunchingWithOptions%3a)

Comment: Hmm, don't know what you mean. That only fires the first time I open the app. If the app still is in the background, that will never happen.

Answer (score 0):

Look up the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey) for UIApplication launch option keys. The last parameter to your application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: delegate method contains the information you need.

Also, look at [application:didReceiveLocalNotification](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application%3adidReceiveLocalNotification%3a).

Comment: That doesn't fire if the app is in the background, which it will probably be.

Comment: Also, didReceiveLocalNotification doesn't tell if the app was already open or if it was opened by the notification

Answer (score 0):

If your application is already running you'll get this delegate message on the app delegate

```
application:didReceiveLocalNotification:
```

If it wasn't running you'll have to use

```
application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:
```

You need to respond appropriately in both methods to cover all cases

**UPDATED**

To detect if the user activated the action button requires a little more complexity. We can tell that `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` will have the local notification as a launch option, but it's more difficult with the `application:didReceiveLocalNotification:`.

Since the application becomes active after the user taps the button, we have to defer until we see that message (or not). Set an `NSTimer` in `application:didReceiveLocalNotification` and cancel it in `didBecomeActive`. That means the user pressed the action button. If the timer isn't cancelled the user was inside the app when it fired.

Comment: Exactly, and I cant tell if the app was opened because of the action button of the notification was pushed or if the event fired while the app was running

Comment: This will also work but I think my solution is cleaner :) thanks though

Comment: agreed, using a timer like this seems hacky :)

Answer (score 0):

In your app delegate in this method:

```
- (BOOL) application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

You have to examine the launchOptions looking at this key:

`UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey`

When you are already active this will be called:

```
- (void) application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
```